# Facebook Open Graph responses id but not showing in profile

Tags: facebook, api

I am trying to realize something with Open Graph: When the user opens a site, it should post to his facebook: *"Herp took a look at 'THE MEMES NAME' on DOMAIN"*. So i got an action called *"Take a look at"* and a object called *"Meme"*.

This is the code to post it:

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/xxxx:look';     
$ch = curl_init();   
$attachment = array('access_token' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
   'meme' => xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    );      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);     
$result= curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
```

THis are my meta tags:

```
<head prefix='og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'>
<meta property='fb:app_id' content='xxxxxxxxx' > 
<meta property='og:type'   content='xxx:xxx' > 
<meta property='og:type'   content='object' > 
<meta property='og:url'    content='xxxxx' > 
<meta property='og:title'  content='".$zeile[2]."' > 
<meta property='og:image'  content='".$image_path."' >
```

So there is also an `og:type` object because the user can like it also.

When I open up this page I am getting as response an id. So everything should work. But when I look at my profile then, there is nothing posted. There should be written *"Derp took a look at 'memename' on xxxxxx"*.

Anyone got an idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> But when I look at my profile then, there is nothing posted. There should be written "Derp took a look at 'memename' on xxxxxx".

I bet you can see it in your Activity Log, though?

AFAIK action publications don’t start showing up in your feed immediately – it takes a few more published actions until they get shown automatically.

Maybe you want to look into [Explicit Sharing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/explicit_sharing/) for your OG actions?